# Button in UITableview modify current cell custom

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I not find a solution to modify my **custom cell** since a button which is inside. I will wish to change the label text when I click the button.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

// View
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:255.0 alpha:0.0]];

// Label
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320-7-7, 16)];
[label setText:@"Hello"];
[label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[view addSubview:label];

// Action
UIButton *action = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(306-54, 0, 54, 54)];
[action setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[action addTarget:self action:@selector(actionMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:action];

// Add view to cell
[cell addSubview:view];

return cell;
}
```

**Edit (add details)**

```
- (void)actionMore:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

// Edit current cell, but I do not know how...

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code of the `actionMore:` method.

Comment: I have add details for the actionMore.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the cell in which the button was pressed with following lines of code

```
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
```

Then use the cell reference to change the label text

cell.yourlabel.text = @"New Text";

**Update**
I think the above code may not work in iOS 7. The better way is

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.mainTable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

Answer (score 1):

To help you need to give some more details.

1. Is this a single cell or is it a prototype for multiple?
2. The code in the actionMore: selector.
3. What are you trying to do this for? Why a button in a cell to change the label text?

If this cell is being used more than once, a problem could be actionMore: can't isolate which cell is the target for the code. Also you could have a simple typo in the actionMore method but we can't solve that without being able to see all of the interacting code.

If you can provide more details, some one may be able to help. I will edit this answer if I can help you once I have more information.

--EDIT--

First to get cell you can use:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
```

Then you can access your cells label by:

```
cell.label.text = @"Some Text Here";
```

Your next issue is figuring out where in the list your cell lies. For that use this code:

```
UITableView * table = (UITableView*)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [table indexPathForCell: cell];
```

You then can then use a switch statement or if-else statements to find which row was triggered.

Comment: It a prototype for multiple cell. I have add details for the actionMore. It is a simple example for understand how modify one cell.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `UIButton` and `UILabel` are subviews of the same view, you can tag your label, and use `viewWithTag` to find it from your button's action code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320-7-7, 16)];
label.tag = 1234;
....

- (void)actionMore:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UILabel *label = [[sender superview] viewWithTag:1234];
    // Edit current cell
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer.  AND you should take advantage of view tagging to make your cellForRowAtIndexPath more efficient.  You're defeating the purpose of cell re-use by re-creating UIView, UILabel, and UIButton even when a re-usable cell is returned.  Use this same viewWithTag trick to get the View,Label, and Button from the re-usable cell then set the properties as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you better add `view` as a `subview` of the `contentview`

pass the `indexpath` to `actionMore` or fetch it from there. once you got the  `indexpath`, you are in business.

you may want to set a tag for your `textlabel` for fetching it from its `superview`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)actionMore:(id)sender{
    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];

    UIView *view = [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UILabel *label = [view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    [label setText:@"test"];
}
```

Comment: You could have skipped the `superview/subview` jump: `UITableViewCell * view = (UIView*)[sender superview]; UILabel *label = [view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];` I think a tag-based solution is more robust than an index-based one.